# What is the current size of Stack?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

Suppose an initially empty stack S has performed a total of 25 push operations,
12 top operations, and 10 pop operations, 3 of which returned null to indicate an
**empty stack**. What is the current size of S?

I'm thinking that S.size  =7 because 10 pop operations have 3 out of 10 returned null to indicate an
empty stack but not really sure  if it's correct or not

Can any one give the correct answer and explanation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You popped a total number of `10-3 = 7` elements, since 3 of the pops
  did not change the state (and size) of the stack, so only 7 pops did.
- You pushed a total of 25 elements.
- Top operations do not change the state (and size) of the stack, and
  can be ignored.

Total size of the stack is `25-7 = 18` at the end.

Note that the order of operations does not matter, only the amount of "succesfull" `pop()`s, and amount of `push()`s.

Comment: if stack has more than 10 elements how come 3 out of 10 pops operation return null .It should not does so , null indicate an empty stack

Comment: @daskinder You have no information on the ORDER of the operations. What if the order was `pop(), pop(), pop(), push() * 25, pop()*7, top()*12`. The first 3 `pop()` return null and do not change the size of the stack, only the last 7 ones do. This is one valid example that meets the conditions described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

25 pushes = 25 index

10 pops = 25 - 10 = 15

3 pops did not occur = 15 + 3 = 18

tops does not matter, so it should be 18

Answer (score 0):

It is the difference between number of push and pop.